# How to start specific systemctl service after login

Tags: boot, systemd

In my local ubuntu server, it takes time to bootup because of some services e.g. hciuart.
I want to start those services after login, instead of at boot time.

If I disable those service with following command

```
sudo systemctl disable hciuart
```

That service remain disabled even after login, and I need to explicitly start it.

```
sudo systemctl start hciuart
```

But what I want is, it should be enabled by itself, but after login OR when boot is completed, i.e. it should not delay my booting process.

Services like this are in path of my boot critical-chain
[image]
Like in above example, I don't need wpa_supplicant at bootup (In above image I already disabled hciuart, that's why it is not visible)

How to start specific systemctl service after login?

Comment: why not fix the problem instead? Is this a raspberry perhaps?

Comment: @Rinzwind Yes, it is raspberrypi, there is no problem, but the requirement is, I don't need hciuart at bootup and similar services, but they take time during bootup, which could be optimized.

Comment: But the reason why this is is a known issue and has a fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

> How to start specific systemctl service after login?

1 possible method it to use a  `systemd` user session. Create the service directory if it does not exist:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/systemd/user
```

Copy the systemd service over to this directory using a new name. I added a 2 and this will enable and list it.

```
systemctl --user enable hciuart2.service 
systemctl --user
```

- might need `root` as a user though as you want to use a device with this and you do not own that.

---

There is a better fix:

Mind that if you do NOT need BT you can keep `hciuart` disabled (and also `blutoothhd`).

The reason for the delay is because `hciuart` takes a long time to reach a timeout when it can not claim `dev-serial1`. And it never will.

So ...

- Remove `Before=bluetooth.service` in `hciuart` service.
- Change `Wants=dev-serial1` to `Requires=dev-serial1`
  Mind that is you do NOT need BT you can keep `hciuart` disabled.

... and it will start without a delay. The BT service will take a second or so to come up.

Comment: It doesn't timeout dude, when enabled, it starts properly, but it takes a little time to start, and similarly many other services, and collectively that time is huge (~1 minute). But I believe it could be optimized, if we can start some services after boot.

Comment: But the points that you specified are helpful, I am checking them. :)

Comment: What about creating an executable file and put it in rc.d directory to start selective services? Please let me know if you know about this approach.

Comment: @afzalex way ahead of you. user session is probably a better opton :)